# Implicit Transaction in Entity Frmework 6 DbContext.SaveChanges()

Tags: transactions, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

According to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336792.aspx), EF6 implicitly wraps `ObjectContext.SaveChanges()` in transaction. Documentation on `DbContext.SaveChanges()` says [nothing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) about transactions.

When I tried to test `DbContext.SaveChanges()` with SQL Server, I saw couple of my inserts in SQL profiler and no transaction operations at all. There was single "audit login" on start containing "set implicit_transactions off".

Have I missed some configuration value or this behavior is "by design" in code-first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SaveChanges` does execute in one transaction, guaranteed. I think it's a big omission that the MSDN docs on `DbContext` don't mention this. But then, its virtually useless anyway. The ADO.Net Entity Framework blogs are the place to be.

Sql Server Profiler doesn't log transaction events by default. If you want to see those you have to select them when you start a new trace, for instance:

[image]

Comment: I suspect something is wrong in our infrastructure. I created new clean context with one entity and unique key constraint and it had being wrapped in transaction during SaveChanges().

Comment: There was occasional external transaction already opened and on saveChanges() EF detects it and does not create nested one.